# Existence of bound state in (higher dimensional) conformal field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

- I'm wondering why correlation function is a more fundamental object in conformal field theory than the notion of particle. By conformal symmetry, I think we can still discuss about massless particle.
- I'm wondering if there will be bound state and scattering state, those exists in quantum mechanics scattering  theory, will they still work in CFT?
- Also, I'm wondering why don't we draw Feynman diagram in CFT and why CFT don't have Lagrangian?

Comment: The notion of particles and correlation functions are not mutually exclusive. Also, CFTs can have Lagrangians, indeed the first example one encounters is usually a mass less scalar.

Comment: Some CFTs have Lagrangians, some don't. Not *needing* to work with a Lagrangian is part of the power of CFT.

Comment: correlation functions are fundamental in QFT too, but here's an old post on particles in CFT: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78552/why-are-there-no-particles-in-conformal-theories