# Does planar (or non-planar) ${\cal N}=4$ SYM contain bound states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, large-n

Does planar/large number of colors ${\cal N}=4$ SYM contain bound states at strong or weak coupling? Are there bound states in the non-planar limit at strong or weak coupling?

Comment: ${\cal N}=4$ Super-Yang-Mills is scale-invariant ([link to pdf](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/fall08/handouts/lecture06.pdf), section 1.2), so this question is related: [Why are there no particles in conformal theories?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78552)